# Same user id in scratch org as in Devhub

Tags: scratch-org, dev-hub, cicd

In my DevHub there is a Apex class that gets return value of an HTTP request based on the Id of a user that runs that Apex class.

I would like to bring this to a scratch org. How can I have users of same id in scratch orgs as in my DevHub?

Comment: Why does it have to be the same id?

Comment: I use user id as a parameter to make http requests.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can't edit salesforce id as explain here :

https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000guv5AAA

The best way is to use a custom externalId field (instead of salesforce 15/18 digit id that will be different in each Sandbox / Scratch Org)

Answer (score 0):

@Zhuang Paulus

It's not considered good practice to hardcode SF Id's in Apex/Formulas etc for just the reason you've found - you can't guarantee the same ID's in other orgs.

It is far better to use some other value - in the case of Users, then their username or alias - and search for that user to retrieve the Id.